# Error "File not found" thrown, even after file is created

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, filenotfoundexception

My code is quite lengthy, but basically, each time a user clicks a button, it runs two methods - read an array of objects from a file. It then appends a new person's details to this array, then the second method writes to the file. First time, in logcat, I get the error "file not found" - expected, cos I haven't created the file yet. Second click, same error. Repeatedly, same error. therefore, I deduce, that something is going wrong, because otherwise it would not thrown an error "file not found" - file was created when writing last time.
My activity code:

```
package com.example.partyorganiser;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddPeople extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_people);
}


///Addpeople is the activity to add people to an arraylist, which is read and then written back to the file

    ///It will then write this to a file in the internal memory of the device, in  CSV like format.


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
    return true;
}
public void addpeople_action_save(View view) {
    EditText et_addpeople_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addpeople_name);
    EditText et_addpeople_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addpeople_number);
    String person_name = et_addpeople_name.getText().toString();///parses from the EditText to a string.
    String person_number = et_addpeople_number.getText().toString();
    ///Next section is writing the two strings to a internal file, as a CSV format.
    ///eg: Bill, 0123567898
    ///this will actually append the string to an arraylist of strings, before writing it back to the file.
    ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_return = Readpeopledetails();///throws error here, presumably, when reading a file that doesn't exist.
    ///but doesn't stop normal program flow....
    PeopleDetails person_details = new PeopleDetails("", "");
    person_details.name = person_name;
    person_details.number = person_number;

    ///need to write arraylists back to file. Will overwrite if exists (contains previous data in arraylist)
    ///or will write a new file if it doesn't exist.
    ///New method(PeopleNumber, PeopleName, Filename)
    ///will write to file.
}
///SORT METHOD:
///Could sort the names and numbers by alphabetical order,

public void addpeople_switchmenu(View view){
    Intent switch_menu = new Intent(this, MenuList.class);
    EditText et_addpeople_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addpeople_name); et_addpeople_name.setText(null);
    EditText et_addpeople_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addpeople_number);et_addpeople_number.setText(null);
    startActivity(switch_menu);
}

public void peopledetails_write(ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_file) {
    ////numbers is the arraylist of numbers.
    ///names is the arraylist of names of people.
    ///Written to file like 01235 678 908, Daniel; 01245 645 123, Bob Marley; etc.
    ///Like a CSV file. 
    try{
        FileOutputStream outputstream_people = openFileOutput("PeopleDetailsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream_people); 

        String filestring = ""; ///initializes filestring, which is written to the file.
        for(PeopleDetails person : peopledetails_file){
            String person_detail_string = "";
            person_detail_string = person.name + "," + person.number;
            filestring = filestring + person_detail_string + ";";

        }
    }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
    }






    }

public ArrayList<PeopleDetails> Readpeopledetails(){
    String filereadfrom = "";///declares a string to read file contents into. then split into peopledetails.





    ///Initialises two arraylists of string. one for names and one for numer.s will be used like paralell arrays.
    try{
        InputStream filestream = openFileInput("PeopleDetailsFile");
        if (filestream != null){///first time file is not created. Later will be created, when writing back to the file.
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(filestream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);

            }
            filereadfrom = stringBuilder.toString();
            ///using two delimiters: ";" and ","
            ///split based on ";" to get people as a string, put in array
            ///then split all strings in that array, based on "," and place each into the array peopledetails
            String[] parsearray = filereadfrom.split(";");
            ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_array = new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();

                for(String personstring: parsearray){
                    String[] split = personstring.split(",");
                    PeopleDetails peopledetails_unit = new PeopleDetails("", "");
                    peopledetails_unit.name= split[0];
                    peopledetails_unit.number = split[1];
                    peopledetails_array.add(peopledetails_unit);

                      ///neatly initializes and writes to the peopledetails_array in one section. 
            }



            return peopledetails_array; }
    }





        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("File not found" , e.toString());
            }

        catch(IOException e){
            Log.e("Can't read file" , e.toString());






        }
    return null;



}
public ArrayList<PeopleDetails> sortList(ArrayList<PeopleDetails> list){
    PeopleDetails[] array = (PeopleDetails[]) list.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i< (array.length - 1) ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < (array.length - 1); j++){
            if(array[j].name.compareTo(array[j + 1].name) > 0){
                PeopleDetails transfer = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = transfer;

            }
        }///based off the common bubble sort algorithm - easy to implement.
        ///if it was a much much bigger data system, this would be inappropriate, with Order(n**2), 
        ///as it uses two for loops each n times.
    }
    ArrayList<PeopleDetails> returnlist = new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();
    for(PeopleDetails item : array){
        returnlist.add(item);


    }
    return returnlist;

}
```

}

Rather lengthy....

Thanks for the help!! :)

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)

Comment: You're never closing the files, for a start...

Comment: shorter code example?? or an example of the problem??

Comment: @SwedishArchitect also there is no need to initialize your edittexts again. You can initialize them in `onCreate` (only once) and declare them as instance variables.

Comment: ok, thanks, quite new to java

Comment: @SwedishArchitect  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal. look at this you will know what jon skeet meant by closing files. also where do you use `osw` or write data to file?

Comment: @SwedishArchitect do you have `PeopleDetailsFile` before reading fomr it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you click the button

You have

```
  ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_return = Readpeopledetails()
```

In  `Readpeopledetails`

```
  InputStream filestream = openFileInput("PeopleDetailsFile");
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/content/Context.java#Context.openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29

```
551     public abstract FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String name, int mode)
552         throws FileNotFoundException;
```

File is not created yet or you do not have a file with name `PeopleDetailsFile` in your internal phone storage . So you get `FileNotFoundException`.

I don't see where you call `peopledetails_write` which is where you have

```
  FileOutputStream outputstream_people = openFileOutput("PeopleDetailsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also you need to write data and close the `FileOutputStream`

If you click again its still not created.

You need to have `FileOutputStream outputstream_people = openFileOutput("PeopleDetailsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);` create a file before you try to open a file.

Also there is no need to initialize views again. You can initialize it in `onCreate` once.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: thanks very much!! this is exactly what I was looking for!! :) my code didn't write to the file, so couldn't read from the file....